Run a project from Visual Studio without opening the IDE
related to Run a solution from Visual Studio console without opening the IDE which was asked 11 years ago.
I am using Visual Studio Community 2022.
I want to be able to build and execute the project only from command line, what are the commands to do that in the recent versions of IDE? Preferably Ubuntu commands so that my project is more portable.
Edit: I tried the commands from the link. The build command is executed successfully but when I run the exec file it does nothing. Im developing a project with SDL2, OpenGL and ImGUI. Double-clicking the exec file from file explorer shows error messages that it cant find the dll files (SDL2.dll etc.)

I think I maybe miss something or don't understand your question. How does the Version of your IDE impact the way you call a project? The original commands from the link you provided look fine to me. Are you experiencing any Issues? Did you actually try this way? And how did that turn out?

@LMA you are right, I updated the post.

Are the .dll's in the same folder or in a related subfolder of the .exe?

@LMA The solution has a "Engine" project and a "Game" project. The .dlls are inside the "Game" project. The x64/Debug where the executable is doesnt have inside the .dlls.

to my knowledge the .dll's have to be somewhat related to the .exe
either in the same folder, subfolder or you set the specific output folder.

for multiple configurations you can try in your csproj file adding something like this




or altering it if you have already

The commands are correct and working, the problem is the path from which you have to execute them. Go to the directory where the dlls are and from there execute the .exe with the corresponding path. That way the .exe finds the dlls and folders it need based on the environment you are in.
